# how to make sharepoint CAML query works more efficienctly

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am now working on sharepoint CAML query. to fetch out item by a given name from a huge resources library which full of images, documents, videos and so on.

I didn't know whether sharepoint index the Name column. I'm thinking to use nested query to make this query faster.

My question here is:
How does sharepoint query work? execute the outer layer first, or start from the inner layer?

I wanna to filter the ResourceType(Image,Document..) first. then filter the category and finally fetch out the items match the name.Is the query bellow work just like what i need?

```
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='IR_ResourcesType' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Image</Value></Eq>
                <And>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='IR_Category' />
                   <Value Type='Text'>All</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                   <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                   <Value Type='File'>aaa</Value>
                </Eq>
             </And>
          </And>
       </Where>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try indexing one of the unique columns in your list so you can use it later on for querying in your where clause.

As best practice, we should also just get the columns that we will be using so as to not have a data buffet. You can limit the columns you will be displaying by using viewFields.

Here is a [link](http://avinashkt.blogspot.com/2008/11/caml-tricks.html) which shows some tips and tricks for CAML in conjunction with SPServices which I think you might find useful.